# Need real world example of using collision filtering in box2dweb

Tags: box2d

I am developing a platform game in boxbox, a wrapper of box2dweb. I want to avoid certain entities not to collide, i.e they can pass through each other. 
Can anyone provide the real world simpler example of using collision filtering in box2dweb or boxbox.

Answer (score 1):

http://codingowl.com/.
This site has an article on `Collision Filtering`. You might want to check it out.

Comment: Categorybits and maskbits can be used for collision filtering among different types of objects. Here I have used the technique to make this game : http://pixsansar.com/box2dweb-jumping-and-puzzle-ball-level4